# note: expected ‘struct filler’ but argument is of type ‘struct Info’

Tags: c, struct

I'm attempting to send a struct from main to a .h file to be manipulated there. Here is the code in my .c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "funcon.h"
enum sign{
positive,
negative
}sign;

enum type{
integer,
floating
}type;

struct Info{
enum sign leading;
enum type out;
char * exp;
char * fraction;
char * binary;
};


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
struct Info stuff;
stuff.exp = malloc(8); 
stuff.fraction = malloc(23); 
stuff.binary = malloc(31); 
strncpy(stuff.exp, argv[1]+1,8);
strcpy(stuff.fraction,argv[1]+9);
strcpy(stuff.binary, argv[1] + 1);
printf("%s\n", stuff.exp);
printf("%s\n", stuff.fraction);
doyourjob(stuff);
return 0;
}
```

This is the .h file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
enum signf{
positive1,
negative1
}signf;

enum typef{
integer2,
floating2
}typef;

struct filler{
enum signf leading2;
enum typef out2;
char * exp2;
char * fraction2;
char * binary2;
};

int doyourjob(struct filler solveme){

if(solveme.out2 == integer2){

    if(solveme.leading2 == positive1){
    int hold;
    sscanf(solveme.binary2, "%d", &hold);

    }else{

    }

}else{//When solveme is a floating type

}
}
```

When I compile I get the error:
function.c: In function ‘main’:
function.c:51: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘doyourjob’
funcon.h:23: note: expected ‘struct filler’ but argument is of type ‘struct   Info’
I've also tried changing struct filler in the funcon.h into Info, but then I get a scoping error.

Comment: It's very bad style to place function definitions in your header files.  Why do you want to pass a struct of type info "stuff" to the doyourjob(...) function which clearly takes a struct of type filler?  If they were pointers you could just cast them, but you're passing the whole struct.

Comment: I wouldn't mind taking in struct type Info but because of the scoping compilation error I assumed I had to rename the struct type in the .h. If that's not the case, how do I send the struct to my .h with all it's information preserved? Is it possible to remove the struct I made in the .h and keep the signature as struct Info to be passed?

Comment: I would move the `struct Info {...}` to the .h file and move the `doyourjob(...)` to the .c file and make it use the Info structure type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The types are incompatible. They need to be both of the same type.
Changing the type to *struct Info* was correct but you also need to move the declaration of struct Info to somewhere *int doyourjob(..)* can see it. E.g. prior to *int doyourjob(..)* in the .h file.

On a side note you should declare but not implement functions in header files. I.e. in your .h add:

```
struct Info {
   // ...
}

int doyourjob(struct Info);
```

Now in a .c file (say doyourjob.c) you have:

```
#include "doyourjob.h"

int doyourjob(struct Info) {
   // Your code here
}
```

Finally you need to compile and link both files.

Comment: Did you delete your old struct decleration. You should have only one struct Info and it should be prior to _int doyourjob(struct Info)_

Comment: Does that mean my original .c I'm working with should no longer have struct Info?

Comment: Yes. You only need to declare the struct once. When you include the header file, (conceptually) the contents of the header file are copied into the source file and that becomes your new source code.

Comment: Ooh okay. After moving the struct and enums to the .h both compiled fine, thanks! I'll mark this as answered. Thank you.

Comment: No problems. Also on a side note it is usually to add something like the following to header files:

     #ifndef _MYHEADERFILENAME_H
     #define _MHEADERFILENAME_H

     // ...
     #endif

Replace MYHEADERFILENAME with the name of the header file. This stops it being included multiple times in the same file and causing compilation errors :)

EDIT: Those should be seperate but comments cannot include code :/